# RStudio: Switch markdown editing mode between Source and Visual changes special characters

Tags: r, r-markdown, rstudio, quarto

I experienced that for `RStudio 2022.02.1 Build 461`, switching markdown editing mode between Source and Visual changes special character `&nbsp;` to `.`. It can be observed by switching markdown editing mode from `Source` to `Visual` and then back to `Source`. Wondering how to prevent this [rstudio](/questions/tagged/rstudio) behavior?

[image: Source mode]

[image: Source mode after switching back from Visual mode]

**Code**

```
---
title: "Test Slides"
format:
  revealjs: 
    chalkboard: 
      buttons: false
    preview-links: auto
    css: styles.css
---

## Intro

-   This is a test 1.

&nbsp;

-   This is a test 2.
```

**sessionInfo()**

```
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[6] methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.1.3 tools_4.1.3    knitr_1.38    
[4] xfun_0.30      pacman_0.5.1
```

Answer (score 1):

The visual editor will by default rewrite markdown for you in the canonical way expected by Pandoc Markdow. `$nbsp;` is a non breaking space in HTML. It get transformed in the source are the non breaking space character in markdown.
See https://rstudio.github.io/visual-markdown-editing/content.html#non-breaking-spaces

If you don't want that the source are rewritten, you can deactivate canonical mode per file or for project / global option. See https://rstudio.github.io/visual-markdown-editing/markdown.html#canonical-mode  and https://rstudio.github.io/visual-markdown-editing/options.html#global-options